# Laravel search in has many relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my Laravel project. I have model Post and Comment. One post has many comments and this is relation in my Post comment. When When I want get all posts and comments all works great:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

I have problem because I want write search engine to models. I want get only posts and only comments where search condition for comments if true. I try this code:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')
        ->whereHas('comments', function($q) use($sort, $search){
            if($sort === 'answered'){
                $q->where('answered', '=', 1);
            }
            if($search){
                $q->where('content', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
            }
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

But this code return all comments to post, not only comments where condition is true.

Comment: you need to add `where` condition in your `with` statement to apply filter in relational data not in `whereHas`.

Comment: are you sure you passing value to `$sort = 'answered'` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must apply the same condition in `with` for achieving this.
Example,

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments' => function($q) use($sort, $search) {
       if($sort === 'answered'){
            $q->where('answered', '=', 1);
        }
        if($search){
            $q->where('content', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        }
    }])
    ->whereHas('comments', function($q) use($sort, $search){
        if($sort === 'answered'){
            $q->where('answered', '=', 1);
        }
        if($search){
            $q->where('content', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        }
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```

I think this will solve your issue. and let me know if it is working